# Dataset.GetXml(); issue in C#

Tags: xml, string, c#-4.0, dataset

I'm reading a CSV file into a dataset and now want to get the xml string. I can not get well formed tags of xml. What do I do here?

> case1:if I use heading in csv files
>
> case2:with out heading.

I need to get same tags heading so that I can use in my code later on.
here is my xml

```
    <NewDataSet>
   <Table>
    <George_x0020_Washington>John Adams</George_x0020_Washington>
    <http_x003A__x002F__x002F_en_x0023_wikipedia_x0023_org_x002F_wiki_x002F_George_Washington>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams</http_x003A__x002F__x002F_en_x0023_wikipedia_x0023_org_x002F_wiki_x002F_George_Washington>
    <Independent_x0020_>Federalist</Independent_x0020_>
    <GeorgeWashington_x0023_jpg>JohnAdams.jpg</GeorgeWashington_x0023_jpg>
    <thmb_GeorgeWashington_x0023_jpg>thmb_JohnAdams.jpg</thmb_GeorgeWashington_x0023_jpg>
    <Virginia>Massachusetts</Virginia>
  </Table></NewDataSet>
```

and here is my code

```
OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection
 (@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties=Text;");
    OleDbCommand excelCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM HS1.csv", excelConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter excelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(excelCommand);
    excelConnection.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    excelAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **case1:if using a header row in the csv files**

If you have header row you should get well-formed XML tags just not good ones depending on your names. You can change your SQL to fix that if you want

e.g. 
     `SELECT [First Name] as FirstName, [Web Address] as WebAddress ....`

> **case2:without heading.**

From your sample XML your CSV file doesn't contain a Header row and is using the values from the first row as the header.

When this happens you'll need to add `HDR=No` to your connection string which will treat the first row as values instead.

From [Connection String Syntax (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500.aspx)

> Connecting to Excel
>
> The Microsoft Jet provider is used to connect to an Excel workbook. In
>   the following connection string, the Extended Properties keyword sets
>   properties that are specific to Excel. "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the
>   first row contains column names, not data, and "IMEX=1;" tells the
>   driver to always read "intermixed" data columns as text.

So your string would be

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No""`

This means however that your columns will be named based on their position. F1, F2, F3.

Again you can rename them in your `SELECT` if you choose to.

e.g. `SELECT F1 as Name, F2 URL ....`